# Creating video tutorials on Linux for my application want to display keystrokes in heads up display?

Tags: keyboard, video-capture

I am running Ubuntu 9.04 and have done about a half hour worth of searching.  I am creating a visual tutorial for a developed application and would like a good looking way to show keys pressed to the user.  While not specifically programming related this is of interest to programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Key Status Monitor](http://programmer-art.org/projects/key-status-monitor).